# Are there any official testing tools from Microsoft for Razor view and Razor pages?

Tags: c#, testing, razor, blazor, razor-pages

I'm doing some research about Razor view, Razor pages and Blazor. Now I do understated the idea but when I came to the testing part I didn't get a great idea about it. For Blazor it's clear for me that there is no official testing tool from Microsoft for it, so people use bUnit or B2B tools, when I came to Razor pages I did see some article about it ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/razor-pages-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) but not very clear about the page itself. And when come to Razor view I didn't get anything about it, so are there any official testing tools for both of them (Just the view and page)?

Regards.

Comment: There is nothing built in, like there is in Rails.

Comment: Okay, then I have to use any tool.